# Binding and Styling a DataGridColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGridColumn like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Binding="{Binding
        Path=Name,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderWrapped}">

    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding
                    Path=DataContext.Name,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The HeaderWrapped style is in a ResourceDictionary that is imported in the control. It looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderWrapped" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I run the app, the header Text is bound properly, but the TextWrapping is not set. I'm guessing that the DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate overwrites the template from my ResourceDictionary. Is there a way that I can keep the styling for the headers in a ResourceDictionary but still bind the Text property of the header?

Comment: Can't you put the `TextWrapping="Wrap"` at the `TextBlock` within the `<DataTemplate>`?

Comment: Yes, but then I'd have to add it to every Column Header. Ideally I'd like to keep all the styling in the ResourceDictionary and bind only the header text in the control.

Comment: If you set a x:Key to your DataTemplate you'll get similar results.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is basically setting a Style for the Header at first, and then tell it to forget about it and use a brand new template for the header. you can't set both `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle.ContentTemplate` and `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate`

However I can think of one workarounds to this problem:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Binding="{Binding
        Path=Name,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Tag="{Binding 
         Path=DataContext.Name,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderWrapped}">
</DataGridTextColumn>

<Style x:Key="HeaderWrapped" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```